# How to get all API tokens from a JSON list

Tags: python, json

So, basically I have a loop that retrieves all of the API tokens I need in order to run another get call.

Here is a segment of my code:

```
tokens = [result['apiToken'] for result in data_2['result']['apiToken']]
for i in tokens:
    url = "https://swag.com"
    headers = {
    'x-api-token': i
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    data = json.loads(response.text)
```

Here is an example of the json:

```
{"result":{"apiToken":"sdfagdsfgdfagfdagda"},"meta":
{"httpStatus":"200 - OK","requestId":"12343-232-424332428-432-
4234555","notice":"Request proxied. For faster response times, use this 
host instead: swag.com"}}
```

With my code I am getting an error on the first line.

> typeerror string indices must be integers

I just do not know how to only pull the API tokens.

data_2 :

```
{'meta': {'httpStatus': '200 - OK', 'requestId': 'ewrfsdafasffds'}, 'result': {'apiToken': 'sdfdagfdfsgsd'}}
```

Comment: Can you post the error you're seeing?

Comment: typeerror string indices must be integers

Comment: it is from that first line too. Sorry about that.

Comment: What does `data_2` look like?

Comment: {'meta': {'httpStatus': '200 - OK', 'requestId': 'ewrfsdafasffds'}, 'result': {'apiToken': 'sdfdagfdfsgsd'}}

Comment: @jdoe what's the result of  `print type(data_2)`?

Comment: that is the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your comment

> typeerror string indices must be integers

try updating your list comprehension (assuming that `data_2` is a list of dicts and not a `JSON` string). It looks like you are iterating over the token characters.

```
tokens = [result['apiToken'] for result in data_2['result']]
for i in tokens:
    url = "https://swag.com"
    headers = {
    'x-api-token': i
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    data = json.loads(response.text)
```

**EDIT2**

So `data_2` may be a `JSON` string, not an dictionary (based on comments). In that case you can try the following:

```
import json

tokens = [result['apiToken'] for result in json.loads(data_2)]
for i in tokens:
    url = "https://swag.com"
    headers = {
    'x-api-token': i
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    data = json.loads(response.text)
```

**EDIT3**

Ok, so

> Earlier in the code I got a response named response.text and I did
>   data_2 = json.loads(resopnse.text)

therefore `data_2` is a dictionary.

```
tokens = [data_2['result']['apiToken']]
for i in tokens:
    url = "https://swag.com"
    headers = {
    'x-api-token': i
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    data = json.loads(response.text)
```

Comment: I actually tried that earlier, and I am still getting that same type error.

Comment: @jdoe is the `json` example in your question what is stored as `data_2`?

Comment: {'meta': {'httpStatus': '200 - OK', 'requestId': 'ewrfsdafasffds'}, 'result': {'apiToken': 'sdfdagfdfsgsd'}}

Comment: Earlier in the code I got a response named response.text and I did data_2 = json.loads(resopnse.text)

Comment: When I use this code the for loop prints out each token individually. Ex:['sdfdfgdsfgd'

Comment: Ex:
['dsfgdsfgdsfg']
['dfsgdfsfads']
['sdgdfgdsfdg']
etc. 
How could I make them all print within one list?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve here; try this  `print ' '.join(tokens)`

Comment: nevermind i just ended up creating a new list and appending each token thank you